# How to update same content control in different context

Tags: ms-word, office365, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am using word javascript Api for developing a word add-in, I need to insert a content control on button click and send a ajax request. In ajax response i need to update the same content control.

I am trying to use following approaches :

1). While inserting the cc in document set tag as **'temporary'** and after getting the ajax response, searching CC using **'contentControls.getByTag'**, but with multiple content control not able to update the correct cc as ajax response could take time so multiple cc will have **'temporary'** tag.

2). After inserting the cc in the document, i tried to load the cc **'ID'** using:

```
var range2 = context.document.getSelection().parentContentControlOrNullObject;
context.load(range2);
```

But it returns undefine.

Please guide me how i can achieve the above requirement. Which is the correct way to do this or can i use the same range object into another word run and update the cc for that range.

Answer (score 0):

this should be really simple to do. When you insert the content control with the API a content control object is returned. This is effectively a handle to that content control.  Once loaded you can later do any operations with it including adding modifying the content. Check out this example on how to do this:

```js
function InsertCCandUpdate() {
     Word.run(function(context) {
        //  we first insert a content control, on this case on the selection!
        //notice we'll hold a reference to the CC in the myCC var:

        var myCC = context.document.getSelection().insertContentControl();
        context.load(myCC);
        
        return context.sync()
        .then(function(){
            // myCC holds a handle to the  contentt control.... then we can update its content
            myCC.insertText(getSomeContent(),"replace");



        })
    });
}

function getSomeContent(){
//this method is just to simulate your  AJAX call.
return("some text from your AJAX call");

}
```

I think this will help you in your scenario.
thanks!

Comment: Thank you, now i am getting id of inserted CC. Do we need to use 'context.load(myCC);' as i am getting contentControl without using it. Please advise.